# Regex with special received signs and replaceAll() throwns errors

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

A function receives something like this with special sign `(,>_$'` and Java replaceAll throwns error.

---

*SAMPLE INPUT*

I got an error if input something like this:

[ FAILED ] **appendtext** variable has with `System.lineSeparator()`:

```
$model_fsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfds->load('fsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfds','dsfsdfsd');
$model_fsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfds->fsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfds->index();
```

No error if input as:

[ OKAY ] **appendtext** variable have simple input with `System.lineSeparator()`:

```
mysomethingmodel
blabla
```

---

*EXPLANATIONS*

**appendtext** goes into String with other combinations:

```
String allappend = "Something simple var" + System.lineSeparator() + "\t{" + System.lineSeparator() + appendtext;
```

Okay. Than it goes into replaceAll with regex and thrown an error:

```
str_list = rs.replaceAll(regex_newlinebracket, allappend);
```

**regex_newlinebracket** is something regex from another function:

```
    public String RegexPatternsFunction(String types, String function_name)
    {        
    // get a rid of special sign

    String function_name_quoted = Pattern.quote(function_name);


    switch (types) {
        case "newlinebracket":
            return function_name_quoted + "(\\s|\\t|\\n)+[{]";
    }

    return null;
    }
```

---

*ERRORS*

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference

```
at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:808)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:906)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2162)
```

or exactly insider appendReplacement function from Matcher.java:

```
               // The first number is always a group
                refNum = (int)nextChar - '0';
                if ((refNum < 0)||(refNum > 9))
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Illegal group reference");
                cursor++;
```

---

*PROBLEM*

Using special characters as for the

```
$model_fsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfds->load('fsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfds','dsfsdfsd');
$model_fsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfds->fsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfds->index();
```

throwns an error in combination of replaceAll as Regex pattern.

A PROJECT WORKS IF NO SPECIAL SIGN.

I'm using `Pattern.quote` to escaping special characters in other words it will not works if come input like `()` and replaceAll using regex.

In C++ Qt, it's works well, in Java not.

Solutions?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating your problem?

Comment: In a short, a function `replaceAll()` thrown an error if come some special signs like `$_->(');` because they should be escaped. In other words function `replaceAll()` can't replace with example of PHP code.

Comment: I think what you need is [`Matcher.quoteReplacement(allappend)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String))

Comment: Yes. Thank you. It's my first time in Java after PHP and Qt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fine (and necessary) that you use `Pattern.quote`. But what's causing the actual problem is the replacement string, since it contains `$` (which is the relevant referencing-character in replacement strings). Luckily, Java provides you with another quoting function just to make replacement strings safe: [`Matcher.quoteReplacement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29)

So just try

```
allappend = Matcher.quoteReplacement(allappend);
str_list = rs.replaceAll(regex_newlinebracket, allappend);
```

Comment: It works. Works with `allappend = Matcher.quoteReplacement(allappend); str_list = rs.replaceAll(selectedfunction, allappend);` solution. Thank you. It's added fine into fine after opened bracket.